# JSON by POST from Python to PHP - Receive "null" back

Tags: php, python, json

I'm trying to learn JSON and have created a very basic PHP script that receives JSON requests from a Python script and simply return the JSON request. Everything works fine except that the returned value to the Python script is "null" for some reason.

PHP:

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    // read JSON input
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    // JSON to variable
    $message = $data->message;

    // Set header
    header("Content-type: application/json");

    // Create and send JSON response
    $response = array('message' => $message);
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Python:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

# Variables
url = 'http://www.some-website.com/function.php'
post_fields = {"message":"It works!"}

request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode())

json = urlopen(request).read().decode()
print(json)
```

The response in Python:

```
{"message":null}
```

Can anybody explain why?

Comment: At this line : echo json_encode($response); Do you have displayed data ?

Comment: Yes, the Python script sends the string "It works" to the PHP script that in turn sends it back to the Python script. I should receive "It works!" instead of "null".

Comment: Can you try to print request variable ? print(request), what does it display ?

Comment: Yes, of course :) The respond is: (urllib.request.Request object at 0x023A3F90)

Comment: Do you open the php or python file ?

Comment: I open the Python file, send JSON request to PHP on the server, PHP returns the JSON to the python script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180733/discussion-between-vieroli-and-lavonen).